# The significance of the hidden $RECYCLE.BIN folder of drives in Vista

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I notice this directory in both my internal and external HDs that I use in Vista.  Is this linked to the Recycle Bin functionality of windows?  Will windows still operate properly if I deleted it?

The reason I want to get rid of it was that there were times when viruses would hide in this directory.  I hardly use the recycle bin anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you configure a drive not to use the recycle bin you can easily delete the folder and windows will still function properly:

Right click on the Recycle Bin and select **Properties**. Highlight the drive you want rid of the recycler folder and clear the Box **Do not move files into the Recycle Bin. Remove files immediately when deleted** and click **Apply**.

[image]

Note: you will no longer be able to restore deleted files on this drive.

To prevent Windows from creating the hidden Recycle Bin folder again, see my answer in this thread:

[How do I get Windows 7 to NOT use the recycling Bin on a removable drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/76707/how-do-i-get-windows-7-to-not-use-the-recycling-bin-on-a-removable-drive)

Answer (score 2):

This folder is where the recycle bin contents are.

It is part of the file system, I am not sure you can easily delete it as it will most likely be denied or get recreated. However, feel free to delete all contents of it. It will not do any harm to your machine, but I personally would rather just manually empty the recycle bin.

Comment: In my opinion, if it was deleted, Windows would just create a new one, I don't see why something as simple wouldn't be taken into account in the process in charge of it.

Comment: @Gnoupi - i have addressed the 'recreation' issue in another thread: http://superuser.com/questions/76707/how-do-i-get-windows-7-to-not-use-the-recycling-bin-on-a-removable-drive