# How to prevent any Windows 7, 8, XP install to write $Recycle.Bin, System Volume Information on multiuse (Android, Linux) FAT32 SD cards/USB sticks?

Tags: windows, linux, usb-flash-drive, android, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Windows 7 to NOT use the recycling Bin on a removable drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/76707/how-do-i-get-windows-7-to-not-use-the-recycling-bin-on-a-removable-drive)

It's not enough if I set up my machine to work properly, I want to be able to use the SD cards and USB sticks in other people's machines as well.

The trick of [writing an empty text file name $Recycle.Bin](https://superuser.com/questions/76707/how-do-i-get-windows-7-to-not-use-the-recycling-bin-on-a-removable-drive/103601#103601) may work with NTFS files, however Windows always wants to overwrite the empty $Recycle.Bin file with it's own directory on a FAT32 formatted USB or SD card.

How to prevent Windows 7, 8, XP to do so?

Comment: I doubt it can be done very easily, if at all. The question is, why bother?

Comment: Because Windows fills up the Recycle Bin, that's why bother. [More here.](http://superuser.com/questions/538780/how-to-prevent-windows-7-to-create-recycle-bin-folders-on-removable-ntfs-usb-d)

Answer (score 1):

The option to delete files immediately is the closest you are going to get. However, it is a system-specific setting, so you will have to configure it on each system you want to use your flash drive on.

Yes, Windows fills up the recycle bin, but it will automatically reclaim the space if it is needed.