# How do I get Windows 8.1 to enable Recycle Bin on a removable drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, ntfs, recycle-bin

I want to use Recycle Bin functionality on my removable USB Sandisk flash drive. i.e. I want to be able to retrieve my file after an accidental delete. A related question exists ([How do I get Windows 7 to NOT use the recycling Bin on a removable drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/76707/how-do-i-get-windows-7-to-not-use-the-recycling-bin-on-a-removable-drive)) but I want to do the opposite.

My drive is a 16GB Sandisk flash formatted NTFS. It is marked as removable. Cannot find a way to enable Recycle bin on it.

Comment: You and the related question poster should swap drives. Everybody wins.

Comment: If you aim at freeing up space this action doesn't buy you anything.  RB just keep records (of loc actions) of your deleted files, it doesn't actually move deleted files.